# How to NOT offset impressions while doing SEO and research?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I'm optimizing my website mainly for ranking in the google search and I've noticed something that bothers me.

So I've had about 300+ impressions for all my pages before starting the optimization. Of course while optimizing you have to search for keywords you want to rank for, `site:yoursite.com` queries to see what's indexed etc.

However, my concern is that now my impressions have bumped up to 3k+ in about 2 days and I somehow think that the majority of those are coming from my searches and browsing. As you can imagine this is lowering my CTR %.

So my questions are a) is lower CTR % hurting my rankings and b) is there a way to not offset my impressions while doing searches?

Apologies if the questions are premature, however I'm still new to this field.

Comment: Higher the CTR higher the positions in Google SERPs; CTR, Bounce Rate and Dwell Time plays an important role in learning the relevancy of search results. CTR more than 5% and gradual increase is said to be good, as you can't capture all the queries to point over your website.

Comment: So I'm doing my self a bad favour by bumping the impressions of my pages when I scroll the SERPs in order to gather some information and I'm doing this extensively?

Comment: If your not clicking on your competitors you will be lowering their CTR as well.

Comment: Your point makes perfect sense, but still... I can't get a real overview of the statistics in Google Search Console to gain information whether what I'm doing works or not.